# Is it common for residential foundations from the 1960s to contain asbestos?

Tags: foundation, asbestos, usa

Is it common for residential foundations to contain asbestos (circa 1968)?  We recently had a drain line extended and I don't recall seeing any protections in place other than light dust masks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For concrete foundations no, asbestos is not an issue. However, the earth in your location may contain asbestos. In Northern California my brother is having a pool installed and they had to monitor for asbestos while digging.

The dust masks are used for cutting concrete or just the dust. The concrete and rock dust is not good to breathe so we usually wear masks.

Comment: Is the asbestos in the soil naturally or is it in the soil because of construction waste generated during the initial building process?

Comment: Naturally , asbestos turns out to be quite common.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know construction material - the "highest chance" to encounter asbestos - is in the roof or ceiling constructions for rooms - even "hanged ceiling" - and in the air vents, parts that need heat insulation